# Is there any open source solution to Installshield's Demoshield?

Tags: wix, installshield, bootstrapper, burn

We have a very old  applications setup launcher developed with Installshield's DemoShield software. We are now looking to replace this with something better.

Although, we are already using Wix Burn with Custom Bootstrapper written in C# and planning to use this technology to build a custom launcher.

Alternatively, we can use C# to build a simple application which would do the same job. But still looking for better and some ready made template based solution.

Are there any open source solutions to this? Any open source code/script based solution would also do the job.

Comment: [**Advanced Installer**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com) has a feature to create autorun CDs/DVDs, but I haven't tested it much ([forums](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/)). I would suggest you do a quick [**github.com**](https://github.com) session - searching for any hits there for "**`CD/DVD autorun browser`**" - or variations on that theme.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Thank you. But Advanced Installer is not open source. We are now considering using hta.